# No linebreak after tags in tidy

Tags: xml, tidy

HI, I have the following input:

```
<p>Hi <span>you</span></p>
```

I'd like to treat this as XML.

I run Tidy on the cmd-line with the following options:

```
input-xml: yes 
output-xml: yes 
indent: no
```

My output is this:

```
<p>Hi 
<span>you</span></p>
```

However I'd like tidy to not pretty-print the xml. I'd like it to respect all white space, and not add that line break. I can't seem to find a way to output XML without pretty-printing. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found a possible solution and posted it at [PHP Tidy removes whitespace and inserts newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147711/php-tidy-removes-whitespace-and-inserts-newlines/15167134#15167134)

The summary is: put `<pre>`-tags around the xml you want to repair, use output-html = true, then remove the `<pre>`-tags and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using JTidy (the Java port of Tidy), the old version on SourceForge had this bug. JTidy has been moved to a [new GitHub repo](https://github.com/jtidy/jtidy), and this particular bug is fixed [in the latest version.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jtidy/jtidy/1.0.3) Switching to this newer version fixed the problem for me.